# All about bitcoin

Tags: transactions

Hi this is Dushyant from India
i heard about the bitcoin craze hence i checked on google and started visiting sites and earned few (hardly) satoshis, etc.
But i dont know what is the exact value of it and how do i use it also in india there is no much craze due to no knowledge of bitcoins...

I am not sure should i continue to click and earn these mini currencies and add upto 1 bit coin(that would definitely take few month) but then not sure what to do with it ?

Comment: You can visit sites of virtual exchanges like vircurex.com or btc-e.com to see how much is one bitcoin worth at each moment. There are now even a couple exchanges in India working with rupees

Answer (score 0):

At the exact moment I write this, 1 bitcoin is worth about (ballpark) US$650. There are (exactly) 100,000,000 Satoshi in a bitcoin. This means that about 1,500 Satoshi is worth one cent (US).

You have a long way to go before you're rich. You didn't think you'd get something for nothing, did you?

Also, be aware that transferring very small amounts of bitcoin may not work, without transaction fees.